# CSS Triangle artifacts

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, artifacts

Using the tips found [here](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/), I successfully achieved a "slanted" div by placing a triangle overtop of an colored rectangle, however I am experiencing some strange artifacts (see below).

[image]

Notice the thin line above the colored section - it is as if the triangle is placed too low.  I often use `10vh` or `10%`, which could introduce rounding errors with non-divisible screen/div heights, but that is speculation.

What causes this issue, and what can I do to fix it?

---

#### Triangle CSS

```
& {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: none;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

#top-left {
    border-right: 100vw solid transparent;
}

#top-right {
    border-left: 100vw solid transparent;
}

#bottom-left {
    border-right: 100vw solid transparent;
}

#bottom-right {
    border-left: 100vw solid transparent;
}
```

When I create a triangle, I specify either the `border-top` or `border-bottom`, with a corresponding negative margin.  In the case above, the height was 50px:

```
<div id = {{attr.direction}} style = "border-top: {{attr.height}} solid {{attr.color}}"></div>
```

```
<div id = {{attr.direction}} style = "border-bottom: {{attr.height}} solid {{attr.color}}; margin-top: -{{attr.height}}"></div>
```

#### JSFiddle

It can be observed in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LsLbgfLo/), not by resizing the view pane but by choosing a responsive view in developer options, and changing the screen size.  To do this in chrome, right click > Inspect > Responsive (from drop down).  This is not merely a glitch in the developer options, however, as it is observed on real mobile devices.  Notice the thin red outline in the image below.
[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle or a code snippet please.